# Taking camping food for Skiing in Val Thorens?

Tags: france, food-and-drink, camping, winter-sports

I am going on a ski trip with Wasteland Ski in January to Val Thorens and the three valleys also.

After looking at some of the restaurants in Val Thorens being quite expensive and the fact that I want to get the most out of my Skiing, I was thinking about bringing some British Army boil in the bag rations with me and a small burner and a canteen.

Will this be acceptable to do so in the resort?

I cannot seem to find anything about laws prohibiting open flame stoves etc.

My plan would be to find some quiet spot on the mountain and just pull out my stove and canteen and get a boil in the bag ration on and then have a brew. Rather than go find one of the busy cafes on the slope.

**-Bonus point question!**

I heard about these special chemical pouch things that you can put boil in the bag camping food in and you snap them like a glowstick and they cook the food while you have it in your pocket. I have tried googling for this but cannot find anything. Does anyone know what they are called?

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is the correct place as it is how this will affect my travel and stay at the location.

Comment: I also think that this is the correct place ...

Comment: The bonus point question **certainly** fits better on [Outdoors.SE]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not do this. I would rather buy some bread and prepare sandwiches every morning and take them in a backpack, together with some drinks. When you are hungry, you can stop wherever you want and eat your sandwiches. There are enough places in Val Thorens where you can get a fresh baguette in the morning. You can even by your sausages, cheese, jam, etc in a local supermarket. Okay, it is a bit more expensive than elsewhere in France, but cheaper (and possibly better) than in a restaurant on the slopes. The food in France is generally good, but the restaurants located on the slopes of these ski factories are an exception.

Moreover, if you go to Val Thorens, chances are high that you will be accommodated in an apartment. There you will have self-catering facilities for the dinner. Thus, you can avoid restaurants altogether. That's how I did when I was a student and went to Val Thorens, Alpe d'Huez, etc for skiing. A that time, restaurants were out of our budget ...

Comment: Yea I was planning that also , hopefully there will be a Carre-four or other supermarche handy. I thought though a warm meal would be good on the cold slopes.

Comment: There are definitely supermarkets in Val Tho. A warm meal is not really necessary. You are doing physical effort. That warms you up. Eating and drinking are quintessential when skiing. You need to take up vitamins, proteins, and all this stuff. But it does not need to be warm. If you are really feeling cold, go inside and have a warm drink. Preferably one without alcohol. That won't ruin you.

Comment: I would suggest you don't skimp on the food. It's not cheap, but the food is mostly worth it. Unless you area really hard up, spend the extra money and get a steak-frites every so often.